# Character $ from XML content is interpreted as a PHP variable

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have a list of XML files as SOAP envelopes that I need to extract information from, but whenever I encounter a value having the character $, php believes it's a variable and gives an error.

See the Item tag from this example.php file:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    xmlns:ChangeRequestPrintService="http://bt2ws.central.sun.com:8088/services/schemas/cr-print">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ChangeRequestPrintService:PrintChangeRequest>
        <ChangeRequest>
            <Id>1-CKWF3T</Id>
            <Priority>1-Very High</Priority>
            <Type>Defect</Type>
            <Number>7077438</Number>
            <SubmittedDate>2011-08-10 19:28:01 GMT+00:00</SubmittedDate>
            <Status>3-Accepted</Status>
            <CrNumber>7077438</CrNumber>
            <Area>Defect</Area>
            <Item> Testng text $c </Item>
        </ChangeRequest>
    </ChangeRequestPrintService:PrintChangeRequest>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
XML;
?>
```

In my main PHP file, the one that I'm executing, I have:

```
$bugXML=new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
```

and the error message I'm getting is:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: c in /path_to_file on line 20.
```

Is there any way I can make PHP ignore it? 
I cannot change the content of the SOAP envelope.

Thanks in advance.

Cristina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

- escape the dollar sign: `Testng text \$c`
- Use [Nowdoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) to disable variable interpolation altogether. This works in PHP 5.3+ only. `$xmlstr = <<<'XML'`  (note the apostrophes).
- Store the XML in an external file (rather than as PHP string literal) and [load it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) then needed.

Comment: Yes `\$c` is the way to go. It does not change the content, only how PHP parses the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: So if I had the XML content in another file (an XML file), how should I open it. What would be the equivalent of what I've done here?  :

include 'example.php';
$bugXML=new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

Comment: @Cristina: an equivalent of the code above would be: `$xmlstr = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/soap-envelope.xml');`, assuming you saved your XML in a file named `soap-envelope.xml` in the same directory as the PHP-script loading it. The code you've provided gets XML as string, not as a DOM or SimpleXML.

Comment: @Cristina: of course, you can also [load it as SimpleXML from a file](http://ua2.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) right away: `$xmltree = simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/soap-envelope.xml');`

Comment: Excellent, Alex! Thank you very much! I've just tried it and it works like a charm.